# "Surround With" in android GUI editor

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Assume that I have a group of views/view groups in the layout XML. 
I want to surround them with another view group.
Is there an automatic option for Eclipse Android GUI editor like "surround with" for JAVA code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Select the widgets in question (e.g., via the Outline view).

Step #2: In the Outline view, right-click over the selected widgets and choose "Wrap in Container" from the context menu.

Step #3: Choose your desired container type and give it an ID value, then click OK.